# How to get reord in Hibernate if there is indirect relationship among 2 tables

Tags: hibernate, relationship

In Hibernate, I have 3 tables table1, table2 and a Master table. table1 has 1-to-Many relationship with Master table and table 2 has 1-to-1 relationship with Master table. My question is , Is it possible to get table1 record using table2 object while there is no direct relationship between table1 and table2 but there is a indirect relationship between both through Master table. Please explain how we can get table1 record using table2 object if possible.

Comment: How would you do it using an SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can form a cartesian join between table1 and table2 and have the indirect relationship expressed thru a where condition.

for ex: 
select a from tableA as a, tableB as b where a.column1 = b.column2 and b.column3 = 10

Hope this solves you problem.

Edit: You can use the above, if table1 and table2 have a column which share common values from Master table but don't have direct relationship.
Otherwise, you will have to use Master table to join / relate table1 and table2.